# can't update scope on ng-repeat leave animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I have an angular animation on an ng-repeat (using jQuery's animate function), and want to update a "Visible" property on the model when each animation completes.  The purpose is to orchestrate multiple animations. I am finding this works fine in the enter function, but does not work in the leave function.  Here is the code:

```
app.animation('.step-animation',
  function () {
    return {
      enter: function (element, done) {
        var scope = angular.element(element).scope();

        jQuery(element).css({ opacity: 0 });
        jQuery(element).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 2000, done);

        return function (cancelled) {
          if (cancelled) {
            jQuery(element).stop();
          } else {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.step.Visible = true;
            });
          }
        }
      },
      leave: function(element, done) {
        var scope = angular.element(element).scope();

        jQuery(element).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 1000, done);

        return function (cancelled) {
          if (cancelled) {
            jQuery(element).stop();
          } else {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.step.Visible = false;
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

The Visible property on my step object is being successfully set to true after the enter animation completes, but it is not updated on the leave animation.  Also - I notice that the $parent property is null on the scope in the leave function, but populated on the scope in the enter function.  It seems like leave is isolated, and enter is not. How can I update the scope from the leave function?

**UPDATE**

I have discovered that the return function is getting called twice in the leave function - once with cancelled = true.  No idea what is causing this, or how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in the iterated collection a DOM template will be rendered and a new scope will be created and associated with it.

The `leave` function in your code is called when one of these templates is removed from the DOM (for example due to `filter`). When the template is removed its associated scope is destroyed.

This means that when the following function executes the associated scope will already have been destroyed:

```
return function (cancelled) {
  if (cancelled) {
    jQuery(element).stop();
  } else {
    scope.$apply(function () {
      scope.step.Visible = false;
    });
  }
};
```

You can verify this by adding the following inside it:

```
console.log(scope.$$destroyed);
```

When a scope is destroyed one of the things that happens it that its `$apply` function is set to an empty function:

```
function noop() {}
```

This means that the anonymous function (the one that sets `Visible` to false) that you pass to `scope.$apply` will never be executed, since `$apply` is just an empty function and doesn't do anything with its passed arguments.

To solve this you can inject `$rootScope` and use that instead:

```
return function(cancelled) {
  if (cancelled) {
    jQuery(element).stop();
  } else {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      scope.step.Visible = false;
    });
  }
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jdNtcOSzq9BC9vxjmmLy?p=preview

Also note that the `element` will already be a jqLite element (or jQuery element if jQuery is loaded before AngularJS) so you can replace the following:

```
var scope = angular.element(element).scope();
```

With:

```
var scope = element.scope();
```

And all occurences of:

```
jQuery(element)
```

With just:

```
element
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help.  I wondered if it had something to do with the leave removing the element, but it didn't occur to me to inject $rootScope.  A couple follow up questions - why does the leave fire the return function twice (one complete, and one cancelled)?  I added logging to your plunkr to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/snf2zz3pp5JszLL0uRZB?p=preview And is there a reason to use jQuery(element).animate instead of just element.animate if the element is already a jqLite object?

Comment: You're welcome :) Oh, forgot about that part. I don't know honestly, but I tried the examples from the Angular documentation and `leave` was called twice there too. I might look deeper into it tomorrow. No, there is no reason to juse `jQuery(element)` as long as jQuery is loaded before Angular. Don't know why I didn't comment on those when I commented on `angular.element(element)`, I must have spaced out :)

Comment: Thanks again - made my day.  If I could upvote again I would! :)  Please let me know if you are able to figure out why leave always makes a cancelled callback.